# Connect two or more modules sharing the same pins?

Tags: arduino-uno

I've found some separate instructions for connecting an SD reader/writer and also instructions for connecting a RFID reader and Piezo Buzzer.  I would like to use both modules and the piezo buzzer together on the same Arduino. See below for the pin wiring details from each instruction I found:

**SD Reader/Writer**

- 3.3v goes to 3.3v on the Arduino UNO (for power)
- GND goes to Ground on Arduino UNO
- D0 goes to pin 12 on Arduino UNO
- D1 goes to pin 11 on Arduino UNO
- CLK goes to pin 13 on Arduino UNO
- D3 goes to pin 10 on Arduino UNO

**RFID Reader**

- SDA - Digital 10
- SCK - Digital 13
- MOSI - Digital 11
- MISO - Digital 12
- IRQ - unconnected
- GND - GND
- RST - Digital 9
- 3.3V - 3.3V

**Piezo Buzzer**

- Red - Pin 8
- Black - GND

Is using the same pin for more that one module ok?

Comment: What RFID reader do you have / what interface does it use? SPI?

Comment: (1) I'm currently using [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B074S8MRQ7/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) RFID reader, but I'm going to change to [ID-20LA](https://www.cytron.io/p-rfid-id-20la) which has a better range

(2) I'm thinking of buying [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/HiLetgo-Adater-Interface-conversion-Arduino/dp/B00HFQEKI0) SD module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pins 11 MOSI, 12 MISO and 13 SCK are [SPI bus](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI). You can connect more devices to the bus. A 'slave select' ('cable select') pin determines which device will communicate. In your table both devices use pin 10 for this. You must change one.

I recommend to wire SD reader D3 to pin 4 and in sketch use `SD.begin(4)`.

Note: some cheap SD card adapters block other devices on the bus and can be used only as single device on the bus